# Blazor passing data @typeparam to parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I would like to create a component by declare TItem and List is data. How to pass its to method parameter of another class.

**Component**

```
@typeparam TItem

<Button Click=OnClickSubmit Text="Submit Order"  >

@code
    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Data { get; set; }
void OnClickSubmit ()
{
    AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass();
    a.Send(Data);
}
```

**In my AnotherClasss was create a method below**

```
void send(List<Person> person)
{
  //I do somethings.
}
```

**why i cannot pass data to send ?**

Comment: How does the compiler know List<TItem> is List<Person>?

Comment: @BrianParker Never know, So how to dynamic convert TItem to any class.

Comment: AnotherClasss  would have to be generic or the Send function converted to generic.
`Send<T>(List<T> list)`

Comment: @BrianParker Thanks you, I will try and send result back to you.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: @QingGuo It not solve yet. But i do other task and find how to solve this problem. please help

Comment: Hello, can you share your AnotherClass?

Comment: @QingGuo I has been reply by my anotherClass

Comment: Maybe you can try to add "public" in front of   "void send<T>(List<T> list)".

Answer (score 0):

Have no what special in this class

```
class AnotherClass { 
     public AnotherClass (){}
     void send(List<Person> person)
     {
       //I do somethings.
     }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).